# Joomla execute function on user login

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I need to execute a internal php function to insert a record in database when user login in joomla. How can I do this creating on component, plugin or extensior?
the event onUserLogin works on joomla 2.5? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

---

You would need to create a plugin and use the event hooks in joomla. So trigger the event and it will talk to your plugin and do w/e it is you want in this case take some user details.

I don't know how to help you code it out if you don't post code so here are some good links to take a look at

Documentation on user events ---> http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Plugin/Events/User

Documentation on events ---> http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events

Notice a lot are being "moved" so click through the links to get to the new pages and notice the name changes in the deprecated events.

Hope this helps and post back some code for more feed back.

Comment: do this will override others plugins that contains onUserLogin function?

Comment: It will not override any plugin hooking into the onUserLogin event.  If your plugin needs to execute before or after another active plugin however, you can alter which plugin hooks fire first by managing their order in the backbend Plugin Manager interface.